# OpenWRT, forward all incoming ipv6 WAN traffic for router’s WAN IP on port 3000 to one PC on LAN with a local ipv6 address

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, ipv6, openwrt, forwarding

I need help with OpenWRT. I want to forward all incoming ipv6 WAN traffic destined for router's WAN IP on port 3000 to one PC on LAN with local ipv6 address.
I have tried

Firewall - Zone Settings => General Settings

[Zone Settings => General Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXFVG.png)

and Firewall - Traffic Rules

[Traffic Rules Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha2FZ.png)

but it I can't get it to work due to my lack of understanding.
Please help

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not just connecting to the PC's _global_ IPv6 address, avoiding the need for "port-forwarding"? Is your ISP not giving you an IPv6 prefix?

Comment: Yes, actually there are other devices on the network and I want to keep all devices and PC on same local network. I just want to clarify if its possible to redirect/forward all incoming ipv6 traffic destined for router's wan interface to the local IPv6 address of PC on LAN side

Comment: Using global addresses doesn't prevent the devices from being on the same local network though...

Comment: ok, but can you clarify my above question? Is it possible without going global?

Comment: Yes, but probably not through the web interface.

Comment: Have you reviewed [NAT6 and IPv6 Masquerading](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/ipv6.nat6) _(I'm making the assumption you're receiving a WAN6 IP from your ISP)_?

Comment: @JW0914 This looks interesting. But I am beginner in openWRT. I think I need to learn more about it and do more research then I'm gonna try this. But right now need a long goodnight sleep :D

Comment: All you need to do is connect via [SSH](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/sshadministration) and follow the steps in chronological order by copying/pasting into the SSH terminal; once done, refresh the applicable LuCI pages and you should see the changes reflected and can view the status/output via the System log by issuing in the terminal `logread -e nat6` _(easier that scrolling through the System log in LuCI)_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks, I'll try this but first I need to confirm that the global ipv6 prefix delegation method from the ISP side is really not working. Then I'll go down this NAT6 path. I'm gonna post an image link here in a short-while in which I'll be able to summarize my problem better in a visual way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal "forward" rules don't change addresses. They just *allow* the packets to go through – but the packets have to be sent to the PC's IP address in the first place.

What people call "port-forwarding" isn't just forwarding, it's actually a *NAT* rule, specifically `DNAT`. (Though a 'forward' rule is still needed, too, but that's secondary.)

OpenWRT's `ip6tables` does support DNAT for IPv6 (in much the same way as it does for IPv4), but as far as I know it's not exposed anywhere in the web UI, so you'll probably need to add the DNAT rule through command line. I don't know how to do that with OpenWRT.

(The reason for it not being in the web UI is that NAT is generally avoided in IPv6 as much as possible – especially "port forwarding" type of NAT, which is just unnecessary.)

Comment: Many thanks for the info and clarification. I guess I just have to go the global route